# MVC 5 only allow external logins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a fresh and clean new MVC 5 web application. I know how to allow external login services like google plus. But one thing I am curious if how do I make it so that they can ONLY use an external login.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all the HTML code that will show the form for regular login, and you should only keep the `app.UseGoogleAuth()` (something similar) and other OAuth providers and the HTML login buttons for those providers.